# PermissionManager for Backpack Laravel -> I want to protect the Routes to Users that only can Edit Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I made this in:
*/vendor/backpack/permissionmanager/src/routes/backpack/permissionmanager.php*

```php
Route::group([
    'namespace'  => 'Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers',
    'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
    'middleware' => ['web', backpack_middleware()],
], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['can:edit permissions']], function () { <---- I added this code
        Route::crud('permission', 'PermissionCrudController');
        Route::crud('role', 'RoleCrudController');
        Route::crud('user', 'UserCrudController');
    }); <---- I added this code
});
```

**It doesn't work**

But I know is not a good idea to do it like this, touching the vendor folder

How can I handle this situation?

Also I've tried to put that code inside the routes of Backpack (/routes/backpack/custom.php), with no results

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, changing things in the vendor directory is a big no-no. But you can easily do the same in your app. You can see in [this package's docs, under overwriting functionality](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager#overwriting-functionality) that there's an easier solution for that:

**Create a `routes/backpack/permissionmanager.php` file. Then Backpack will load YOUR file, instead of the one in the package.**

Remember to include ALL routes from the vendor file and all your overwrites too. The file in the vendor will no longer be used.

Comment: Thanks, Christian!
But also Route::group(['middleware' => ['can:edit permissions']], function () does not work. It gives me always a 403 error. And the user has this permission

Comment: The middleware doesn't work.
Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607554/using-middlewares-in-permissionmanager-for-backpack-laravel

Comment: Hmmm never seen spaces in permission names... could that be it?

Comment: That functionality is offered by https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission - did you check there too?